# Samsung Galaxy S2 can't write any files to SD nor delete existing folders, why?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sd-card, rom

I go to recovery mode, format everything that's possible, even running some full wipe script, then install fresh ROM, boot into it and see all old folder on internal SD card from old apps, also I cannot delete them and I cannot write new files, it just won't save, if I try to take a photo, it gives a warning that no room left on SD card...

I don't need any of the data on the phone, I just need to wipe everything and start from clean blank ROM flash...

Why is that happening and what could be done to fix it?

Comment: An exact error message would be very helpful

Comment: Which Android version? Sounds like Kitkat with its "great new security feature".

Comment: ROM is Based on XWLSW Android 4.1.2 (Date: 16/05/2013).

Comment: Error message when I make a photo with camera:
Not enough space, delete unnecessary items ...